# Php match from center

Tags: php, regex

I have string like below:

```
<a href="test1.com">test1</a><a href="test2.com">test2</a>
```

And my regex is like below:

```
<a href=(.*?)test2.com(.*?)<\/a>
```

and my php code:

```
preg_match('/<a href=(.*?)test2.com(.*?)<\/a>/s',$game,$mat);
```

So I want to match this whole thing `<a href="test2.com">test2</a>` , but instead its matching from the beginning of `<a href` and I get following:

```
<a href="test1.com">test1</a><a href="test2.com">test2</a>
```

How do I match from `test2.com` and match till first left and first right occurances.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/522479)

Comment: This seems painfully prone to issues. Have you considered the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#example-6357) class?

Comment: I thought learning , html DOM for this simple thing is waste of time .. check mrzasa solution is simple and perfect.

Comment: Good luck to you then...

Comment: If I want some deep parsing  , I will ofcourse learn DOMdocument ,thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<a href=([^<]*)test2.com([^<]*)<\/a>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zy9LMP/1/)

Using `[^<]` instead of `.*?` assures that repetition will match only text to next html tag (starting with `<`). Greedy operator with negated class is also faster than lazy operator with dot.